# Why is my port forwarding not working?

Tags: http, xampp, portforwarding, huawei-mobile-services

I installed XAMPP on my Windows machine and I want to show my work to friends. I set up Virtual server on router(Huawei B315) and when I send my public IP to friends or try to open on my computer it doesn't work. It shows me "This site can’t be reached" message. I disabled firewall on both computer and router but it is still the same. Pinging my public IP address is also not working.

Comment: 'Setup a Virtual Server on Huawei B315` - what exactly do you mean setup a virtual server? A virtual server is not necessarily port forwarding. You will need to port forward port (80) from your WAN interface to the IP address of your computer running the WebServer.

Comment: The ICMP packets (ping) may be turned off on your router so that random bot-nets can not actually determine that there is something listening on the IP. This is probably another configuration option.